# Says that my variable is 45 degrees and not valid

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to run Solve[2x+1==6,x] and it has given me an error saying 45 degrees is not a valid variable. How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess you have previously set x to be 45 degrees. Clear it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of junk stored in the variables. To clean it up:

```
Clear[x]
Solve[2 x + 1 == 6, x]
```